# How to perform maximum likelihood fitting when you don't have a probability function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, epidemiology

I was reading a paper on epidemiology by [Greer et al](https://bmcvetres.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12917-016-0922-2), and I was confused about the following point:

"Best-fit model parameter values are obtained using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) by fitting the model to the cumulative incidence data."

However, the paper does not specify a likelihood function. Their model is not formulated in such a way that a specific probability function is introduced.

The model (called 'IDEA') that they describe is:

$I_t = \left( \left(R_0 /(1+d)^t \right) ^t \right)$

where:

$I_t$ is the number of incident cases in each epidemic generation (the response)

$R_0$ is the basic reproductive number (a parameter to be estimated)

$d$ is a control parameter (to be estimated)

$t$ is the epidemic generation (which is an index, time=1, 2, etc).

We have true values for $I_t$. The goal is to use MLE to find best-fit parameters of $R_0$ and $d$. We can easily get the cumulative incidence data.

My question is, once I have the cumulative incidence data, what form does the likelihood take?

I tried following the advice [on r bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-model-by-maximum-likelihood/), by assuming residuals follow an exponential distribution (hard to tell, we only have 38 observations, and note "t" above has been changed to "x" to avoid confusion with `t.test` etc):

```r
    library(stats4)
    
    LL <- function(r, d, lambda) { # assuming exponentially 
                                   # distributed residuals
        R = y - (r/((1+d)^x))^x
        R = suppressWarnings(dexp(R, lambda))
        return(-sum(log(R)))
    }

    mod2 <- mle(LL, start=list(r=1, d=0.05, lambda=1))
```

I also tried with normally distributed residuals, and in both cases I ended up with estimates that were wildly inaccurate compared to those in the paper.

How should I formulate the likelihood?

EDIT: I forgot to add an important point: the observations (in this case the incidents) are not independent. One individual can (and does) infect other individuals.

Comment: Your edit makes it clear that you haven't completely characterized the model.  In order to write a likelihood you need to provide information that will enable us to *quantify* the dependence among the incidents.

Comment: Yes, that's what makes this so confusing: the paper gives no such information. How can they possibly formulate a likelihood?